# Autotransformer design -- how many turns?

Tags: transformer

Let's say I have a 25 ohm resistor, a 28MHz oscillator, and some wire with which I can make an autotransformer. The goal: make the oscillator see a 50 ohm resistance (or something reasonably close to it):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMq3ZK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now here's the question: The turns ratio will obviously be dictated by the transformation required, but in total I can make T1 with few turns or with many turns. How do I decide? What are the tradeoffs involved?

Comment: You need to define the output impedance of the sine wave source.

Comment: @LeonHeller Can't it be treated as an unknown variable in an equation? Surely, engineers aren't taught how to make transformers for sources with \$10\Omega\$ output impedance, then separately taught how to make transformers for sources with \$20\Omega\$ output impedance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's running from an oscillator then the frequency is fixed therefore you can tune the auto-transformer so that there is minimal reactive load to the oscillator. A 33pF capacitor and a 1uH coil are resonant at about 28MHz but do some tweaking so that the unloaded inductor and capacitor are near enough fully resonant at 28 MHz.

All that is left is to pick a "tap" that is 70.7% of the turns up from 0V - this will make the 25 ohm resistor like a 50 ohm resistor when seen at the oscillator terminals.

The ratio of impedance is proportional to turns squared so 1/0.707 squared = 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffM90T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's what a simulation looks like with and without tuning capacitor using an auto-transformer with 1uH end-to-end.

[image]

Fortunately the blue curves show virtually the same performance attenuation-wise i.e. 6dB down at "Vout" on the simulated circuit but note that the red curves (phase angle) tell the truer story at 28 MHz - it's subtle but the circuit with the resonating capacitor has a phase angle of precisely zero at 28MHz. Without the tuning capacitor, the frequency would have to be well-over 100 MHz before this was as precise.

---

Just a further note about the inductance values on the circuit I simulated. These are based on a "pretend" 10-turn auto-transformer having an inductance of 1uH - this implies an \$A_L\$ of 0.01uH i.e. 10 turns squared x 0.01 = 1uH. 7.071 turns would give 0.5uH and 2.929 turns yields 0.086 uH.

The formula is a bit tortuous but is based on total inductance (Ls) being L1 + L2 + 2\$\sqrt{L1\cdot L2}\$. If you know the total inductance you require and you have one of the other values i.e. L1 then L2 is: -

\$L_2 = L_1 + L_S - \sqrt{(L_S + L_1)^2 - (L_S - L_1)^2}\$

Comment: What if I don't have a capacitor, or I require it to work at other frequencies? Can you please elaborate on the reactive load added by the transformer? Is there a way to calculate it and minimize it?

Comment: I think the only way to minimize the reactive load is by tuning it or making it so large it barely has a loading effect.

Comment: So, is the reactive load seen by the oscillator just as if it were driving a \$1\mu H\$ inductor and \$50\Omega\$ in parallel (neglecting parasitics)? Or does the fact that this is an autotransformer make it effectively some other inductor? In other words, if I want to consider the option of making the inductance so large that in has negligible effect, how do I calculate what effect it has, so I can decide how much inductance I need for it to be "negligible", however I define that?

Comment: It'll see it as 1uH dude - it's the magnetizing inductance hence the inductance as if the load wasn't connected.